# Самые известные средства парсинга?

Tags: php

Кто какие использует?

Comment: symfony/dom-crawler

Но вообще из вопроса не понятно почти ничего. Что парсится? Какой должен быть результат? Есть ли какие-то правила, которые можно перекинуть в код, однотипные ли будут результаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам необходимо распарсить какой-то простенький фрагмент, то можно не заморачиваться и пользоваться cURL: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

А затем искать нужный текст регуляркой.
Также можно заюзать PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Мне нужно парсить страницы по навигации

Comment: Тогда лучше юзать PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Answer (score 2):

ctrl c - ctrl v. а если серьезно, то очень удобный способ - это парсить RSS ленту, если такова имеется. Разметка универсальная, один парсер может подойти к многим сайтам. Ну а если нет RSS - то подгонять свой скрипт под каждый сайт отдельно. Как писать парсеры - в интернете материалов [куча](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20php)